# How do I .split this string which includes quotes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

The code I am working with is from a jquery-tokeninput fork which allows multiple NEW tokens to be entered in the box (not just ones that already exist). The format of the string that it returns when they click submit is this:

`16,42,'Subway',37,'McDonald\'s',734.`

Those are ID numbers for the tokens that exist, and for ones that don't exist it wraps them in 'quotes'.

My question is how do I change my new_custom_tokens method to interpret whether they have entered a new token or not (check if its in quotes). Ultimately its going to check if their account is old enough to add new tags, and then I need to run Tag.new I assume (so it only saves it when their completely valid, including the resource validations)

EDIT: I also think i need some kind of validation that wont split things within quotes

resource.rb

```
  def tag_tokens=(tokens)
    self.tokens_list = tokens.split(",")

    if new_custom_tokens?
      custom_token_time_restriction
    else
      self.tag_ids = self.tokens_list
    end
  end


  def new_custom_tokens?
    if self.token_list ... #... not sure
  end


  def add_new_tag_time_restriction
    # TODO: Check if they are anonymous or their account is newer than 7 days
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do the trick:

```rb
def new_custom_tokens?
  self.tokens_list.each { |token|
    return true if token.include? "'"
  }
  false
end
```

Basically it loops through the token_list array and returns true if any of the tokens have the ' character.

Comment: is there a difference between using .each do ?

Comment: Nope, they are exactly the same thing. I prefer curly braces for blocks inside functions because it's easier to distinguish what's ending the two blocks.

Comment: You can be more succinct and use self.tokens_list.any? { |token| token.include? "'" }

Comment: AH! Yes Salil! I had a brain lapse when I first posted this and was like "what's that "any" function that works again??"